# div:hover works oddly in IE-8

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-8, excel, vba

I know that this might be ridiculous and you might say why you are trying to invent the wheel but this is what I am currently doing as an experiment which will help me in future projects and currently it is totally of no financial profit for me.

the whole concept is:

- I wrote a piece of code in Excel-vba which opens an instance of IE, allowing me to append my java-script code to the content of a webpage and execute it (a fledgling and not comparable counterpart for Firefox Greasemonkey). So far a success.
- My java-script code adds a menu which is basically a narrow bar at the bottom right corner of the page but when your mouse enters it, its outerHTML turns to:

  ```
  <DIV style="FILTER: alpha(opacity=95); WIDTH: 450px; HEIGHT: 250px" id=alwaisible>
      <DIV id=dummy onmouseenter=menuButton() onmouseleave=menuButton()>
          <DIV id=MenuButton>_</DIV>
          <DIV id=MenuTitle>Ikariam Assistant</DIV>
          <DIV id=MenuBody>
              <DIV id=MenuBar>
                  <DIV class=MenuChoices onclick=Choice(1)>Location</DIV>
                  <DIV class=MenuChoices onclick=Choice(2)>innerHtml</DIV>
                  <DIV class=MenuChoices onclick=Choice(4)>Call App</DIV>
                  <DIV class=MenuChoices onclick=Choice(5)>Extra 1</DIV>
                  <DIV class=MenuChoices onclick=Choice(0)>Extra 2</DIV>
                  <DIV class=MenuChoices onclick=Choice(0)>Extra 3</DIV>
                  <DIV class=MenuChoices onclick=Choice(0)>Extra 4</DIV>
             </DIV>
             <DIV style="HEIGHT: 161px" id=MenuRest>Nothing for now!</DIV>
         </DIV>
     </DIV>
  </DIV>
  ```
- Aamong the whole CSS styling applied my problem is with .MenuChoices and .MenuChoices:hover classes which look as follows

  ```
  .MenuChoices{ 
      border: outset 2px #C7B581;
      color:#FFFFFF;
      background-color: #403924;
      margin: 2px 0px 0px 2px;
      float : left ;
      display : block ;
      width : 82px ;
      text-align : center ;
      z-index : 5001 ;
  }
  .MenuChoices:hover{
      background-color:#456789 !important;
      cursor: pointer;
  }
  ```

Now the problem is, while I browse different sites **I always get my mouse cursor changed whenever it enters one of the MenuChoices** but only **in one certain site the ackground-color changes** and on the rest of times the color change happens only when I click a choice two or three times consecutively, as if the background change is set for the :visited pseudo class! my current IE version is 8.

Any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: Is IE8 in Standard mode? Correct Doctype, etc That could explain the problem.

Comment: What is with all of the missing quotes?

Comment: Please note that making the divs clickable and use cursor pointer will a) not work with screen readers and b) not make the items a tab stop, hence not keyboard navigational. Not very `accessible` of you

Comment: Thanks for your comments so far well I do not have any idea how to determine if IE8 is in standard mode so if you let me know how to check it I would be grateful. as for the missing quotes as I mentioned the whole menu is created through java-script and appended to the DOM of the page so it looks exactly like what you see in the code. currently I am not concerned with the accessibility of the menu but thanks for the notice.

Comment: the problem is that the behavior of the menu is different depending on the page I am browsing. the question is why it is so. and why most of the times the class affects the page partially. and in that certain site what did they include in their page/CSS styles that let the class work correctly.

Comment: @EhsanEnami You haven't answered @Felipe's question: What's the `DOCTYPE` of the webpage?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, only certain html tags work with :hover in IE8. Things like "a" will work, div will not.

For more info, please see this [link](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t16)

Comment: That was the case with IE6 (`a` and I believe form elements). IE8 in Standard mode should be OK but maybe not in quirks mode

Comment: my :hover class works but the problem is that it just changes the pointer not the back-ground color!?